# Oracle SQL report of user first logged in, first activity of the day and last activity of day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, audit

I have a requirement to produce a daily report at the end of the day to track user activity.
I need to report for each user first logging on time, if possible first activity too, then last activity and if possible logging off time.

***optional.***
It might be good to also record the amount of activity for the user.

I have been looking at Oracle tables/views dba_audit_trail and v$session but can't seem to find a query or an example which may do this online.

Should I look at other tables?

I'm currently on an Oracle 11g database.

thanks Shaun

Comment: Does each user have a distinct database account that opens a session at the beginning of the day, keeps it open all day, and then closes the session at the end of the day?  I suppose that is possible if all your applications are client-server apps but generally that would be unusual.  Is your database configured to audit logins and logouts?  What about "activity" for whatever that means to you?  That's possible but that would generally be quite a bit of audit data to wade through.

Comment: Each user has his own user account to logon to the Oracle forms application, I think management are looking at tracking when the user first logged on in the morning and either his log off time (if he does log off, the system logs him off later if he hasn't) or his last activity on the system.

Comment: OK.  And each user has exactly 1 session for the day?  Are you auditing logins and logouts?  Do you just want to capture when the last activity took place or what that activity was?

Comment: The last activity that took place and what it was would be great.

Comment: You could audit logins, logouts, and every SQL statement to produce this report.  But the requirement seems fishy to me.  What would anyone do with the information on the "last activity"?  From a database perspective, the "last activity" is almost always going to be some little housekeeping query or a query that is a tiny part of a much bigger operation.  It seems unlikely that this would be useful to anyone.  Most likely, you need the developers of your application to add more logging that indicates actual human-meaningful chunks of work.

Comment: I'm going to wager that someone really wants to know that the user "filled order 12345" rather than the last SQL statement which was, say, "select sysdate from dual" because the last thing the application does in painting the screen that says "Order 12345 filled at 1:23 pm" is to grab the `sysdate` from the database.